# grant a user to execute only one stored procedure but can't run other queries

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to grant a user execution on a stored procedure but prevent him of running other queries even if he typed the exact same stored procedure?

Basically what I'm trying to achieve here is to prevent a user to see all rows in a view(select all from View1), but he can select only one row with 'where' condition by a stored procedure.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow.  Have you considered posting it (or searching for the answer) on StackExchanged Database Administrator forum?

Comment: I wouldn't really call it off-topic. Granted, it would probably be a better choice to ask this question in the DBA forum, but that is only due to that being specifically about database administration. SO, is just more generalized.

Comment: @c00ler Did either, or both, of the answers below help you out? If so, you should upvote and (or at least) accept one as the answer to close this question and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, simply take away all the permissions of that user and grant the user only execute permission on a single procedure.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.ProcedureName TO [UserName];
```

or

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.ProcedureName TO [UserName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a view for that user that is limited to only the data that particular user has access to? No need to have a stored procedure for simply accessing a row of data.

By using a limited view, the user can choose to incorporate that view record into a query as a `JOIN`, or write their own stored procedure/function as they see fit. A view would be a more flexible way to do what you are attempting.